# PHP - sudo command - don't show root access in error log

Tags: php, system, root, error-log

I'm running a command via php that requires root access. As an example :

```
$cm = "echo $pd | sudo -S cat filename";
system($cm,$rs);
```

This works fine, but in my apache2 error_log I get entries of :
`root's password:`

Is there anyway to stop these messages appearing in the error_log ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I would add the command to the sudoers file. That way it wont prompt you for a password it just knows you are allowed to run those commands.

https://www.garron.me/en/linux/visudo-command-sudoers-file-sudo-default-editor.html

Comment: Thanks this is a locked down box, so I can't add the command to the file.  It's not an issue, but I was hoping to make it neater.